# Draw a horizontal line at the first cadle close price of the day

Tags: pine-script

I am trying a script. I want to draw a horizontal line at the first cadle close price of the day. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ta.change(time("D"))` to figure out if it is a new day. Then use a `var` to keep track of the close price.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

is_new_day = ta.change(time("D"))

var float first_close = na
first_close := is_new_day ? close : first_close

plot(first_close)
```